# Lighthouse Audit: What does 'A url not in devtoolsLog was used for first-party check' mean?

Tags: bundle, source-maps, lighthouse

When running a Lighthouse Audit on my site it found an error with the source maps. However, it doesn't point to any specific place or error. The only information I have is when I hover over the error (as shown in the screenshot) that reads "A url not in devtoolsLog was used for first-party check."

After a lot of searching on Google I haven't been able to discover what this means? Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Thanks.